# How to prevent brute force file downloading on S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm storing user images on S3 which are readable by default.

I need to access the images directly from the web as well.

However, I'd like to prevent hackers from brute forcing the URL and downloading my images.

For example, my S3 image url is at http://s3.aws.com/test.png

They can brute force test and download all the contents?

I cannot set the items inside my buckets to be private because I need to access directly from the web.

Any idea how to prevent it?

Comment: The first suggestion would be to not have predictable filenames...

Comment: Echoing what @RowlandShaw stated, you could try using something like UUIDs as the file names.

Comment: @mbaird, but that doesn't prevent brute forcing. they could get at least a hit in like 1 million try.

Comment: nope. that's not how brute forcing works. If they don't know the key for the object store and don't have a way of guessing it the odds of getting something are practically 0.

Comment: @Mircea, given that they know the length of the key, they can basically generate all the random string with that length and then search through it. If I have million of files, they will hit at least once in a while?

Comment: well. not really. if you have a million files and they know the length of the filename. Let's assume the file is 32 characters long and it's randomly generated. Let's assume each character can be either a-z or 0-9 so you have 36 characters. The total number of combinations would be 36^32 ~= 6.3340287*10^49. That 10^49. Assume your attacker can check 10.000 / second. It would take them 10^45 seconds which means 3.16887646 × 10^37 years The universe will end before they can check all the keys.

Comment: A million files (if the name is randomly distributed) will just cut a few zeros from the numbers above for the scenario in which they want to guess just one filename. The universe will still end until they guess. Also remember that you can increase the length of the filename + use other characters in the name (uppercase, special symbols etc). Again the odds of guessing are 0 for any practical purpose if you do a good job generating the names.

Comment: @Mircea, I understand now. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using good security does not impact your ability to "access directly from the web". All content in Amazon S3 can be accessed from the web if appropriate permissions are used.

**By default, all content in Amazon S3 is private.**

Permissions to access content can then be assigned in several ways:

- Directly on the **object** (eg make an object 'public')
- Via a **Bucket Policy** (eg permit access to a subdirectory if accessed from a specific range of IP addresses, during a particular time of day, but only via HTTPS)
- Via a policy assigned to an **IAM User** (which requires the user to authenticate when accessing Amazon S3)
- Via a time-limited [**Pre-signed URL**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html)

The most interesting is the **Pre-Signed URL**. This is a *calculated* URL that permits access to an Amazon S3 object for a limited period of time. Applications can generate a Pre-signed URL and include the link in a web page (eg as part of a `<img>` tag). That way, your *application* determines whether a user is permitted to access an object and can limit the time duration that the link will work.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep your content secure, and use [Pre-signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) to allow access only for authorized visitors to your web site.  You do have to write some code to make it work, but it's secure.